# Не понятно поведения метода Array.map() в class

Tags: javascript

всем...

Есть такой `class` у меня.

Не могу сообразить с чего вдруг в методе `getName` данного класса странно ведет себя метод `Array.map()`

Чтобы увидеть данную проблему, раскомментируйте нижнюю строку и закомментируйте  верхнюю.

Разница в них, только в `{}` фигурных скобках.

А вот в `getData()` такой проблемы не наблюдается...

```js
//const arrayHtml = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, templateDir));

const arrayHtml = ['index.html', 'dash.html', 'zoo.html'];
class DataSiteConfig {
  constructor(folder, favicon) {
    this.name = name;
    this.favicon = favicon;
    this.folder = folder;
    this.pageList = [];
  }
  getName(dirNameFiles) {
    this.name = dirNameFiles.map((s, i, arr) => s.slice(0, -5));
  //this.name = dirNameFiles.map((s, i, arr) => {s.slice(0, -5)});
  }

  getData() {
    this.name.map((s, i, arr) => {
      this.pageList.push({
        title: s,
        template: `frontend/html/${s}.html`,
        filename: `pages/${s}.html`

      })
    })
  }
}

let dataSiteConfig = new DataSiteConfig('Zona', 'Chtoto.png');
dataSiteConfig.getName(arrayHtml);
dataSiteConfig.getData();
console.log("TCL: dataSiteConfig", dataSiteConfig);
```

Кто подскажут, почему так...

Comment: Не хочу разбираться в коде, но это совершенно разные функции. То что в `{...}` - не возвращает результат. Вот так они должны вести себя одинаково `{return s.slice(0, -5)}`

Comment: Благодарю.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного ошиблись с синтаксисом. 
Тело стрелочной функции может иметь краткую (concise body) или блочную (block body) форму.
Этот вариант:

```
this.name = dirNameFiles.map((s, i, arr) => s.slice(0, -5));
```

работает, потому что в стрелочных функциях мы можем не писать скобки, если нужно вернуть что-то, что пишется в одну строку. Это аналогично записи:

```
this.name = dirNameFiles.map((s, i, arr) => {
  return s.slice(0, -5);
});
```

Если написать скобки и не указать `return`, то возвращаться будет `undefined`, в полной форме записи это выглядит примерно так:

```
this.name = dirNameFiles.map((s, i, arr) => {
  s.slice(0, -5);
});
```

из-за этого каждый элемент массива будет `undefined`.

Код в `getData()` работает исправно, потому что там ничего не возвращается, а просто проходится цикл. Там вообще нет особого смысла использовать `map()`, потому что `map()` возвращает измененный массив, а в `getData()` идет обычный проход по всему массиву.

[Документация MDN: Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Благодарю.......

Comment: Банальная опечатка...